# Concatenate Columns with specific number of registers using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to create a dataframe that concatenates many columns, but each element that I concatenate has to have a certain number of values to follow a specific layout.
For example, I need to concatenate name and last name, but the name always has to have 50 characters, even if the name is shorter, to follow a certain require layout. I should add spaces to cover up for the missing letters in the name.

I'm using this code, but it is not giving me the desired result:

```
df.select(concat(rpad($"FirstName", 50, " "), rpad($"LastName", 50, " ")))
```

Does someone have any tips on how I can do this?

Comment: Are you working with spark?

Comment: Yes! I'm using spark

Comment: The problem seems to be that it is ignoring the spaces. When I add a new "character" such as ; or . it correctly generates as many . or ; as I need

Comment: Do you expect 100 as a string length after concatenation here? In general, the length of the resulted field must be a sum of padded value lengths?

Comment: Yes, I expect 100 as a string length after I do the concatenate. So you mean that in the second rpad I should put 100 instead of 50?

Comment: Got it. No, I think your original code is correct. It gives 100 as value length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your solution is correct. Please set truncate = "false" in `show` method in case you are using spark-shell to check it visually.

Here is test DF data:

```scala
scala> df.show
+---------+--------+
|FirstName|LastName|
+---------+--------+
|     John|   Smith|
|    James|    Bond|
+---------+--------+
```

Now if we print concatenation result and add length as separate column we get exactly the sum of lengths:

```scala
scala> df
  .select(concat(rpad($"FirstName", 50, " "), rpad($"LastName", 50, " "))
  .as("concat"))
  .withColumn("lenght", length(col("concat")))
  .show(100, false)
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+
|concat                                                                                              |lenght|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+
|John                                              Smith                                             |100   |
|James                                             Bond                                              |100   |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+
```